# Feeding behavior of organisms that prey on microorganisms

Tags: zoology, microbiology

Is there a specific term for organisms that feed on micro-organisms?

Answer (score 1):

Use "-vore" and "-vorous" suffix [L. *-vorus* devouring, eating (cf. *vorāre* to devour].

For example: bacteriovores, algaevores, and planktivores.

---

Note: "Microorganism" is an unfortunate, albeit popular (viz. "microbiology") term. How small is "micro"? So small that one needs a microscope to see it? And what kind of microscope: "light" or "electron"? i would drop the term "microorganism" altogether. One can use "bacteria, "archaea," "chromists," "protists," . . .